# Pasar datos de tipo input a una gráfica de chartjs

Tags: html, chart.js

Tengo una página con respuesta de type "Radio" en html y quiero que al seleccionar la opción de mostrar resultado me muestre un gráfico en chart.js

este es el html pero no sé cómo hacerle:

¿Se puede hacer en js o cómo se puede hacer para que me muestre en otra página el resultado?

```html
    <h3>Trabajo</h3>
          <p>Hago lo necesario para avanzar en mi trabajo o empresa</p>
            <p>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="1"/> 1</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="2"/> 2</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="3"/> 3</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="4"/> 4</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="5"/> 5</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="6"/> 6</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="7"/> 7</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="8"/> 8</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="9"/> 9</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="A1" value="10"/> 10</label>
            </p>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, en si falta detalles para poder ayudarte, pero sí que es posible hacerlo con JS, te dejo un ejemplo para orientarte: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_pie_chart, respecto a tus inputs, puedes crear una acción onchange de JS y envías sus valores para crear el chart.

Comment: Por favor, adjunta un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: recuerda que tu pregunta no debe parecer [un ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask].